# Known database situation - two tables with relation to each other insert

Tags: database

We have two Tables.
Table A and Table B.
Table A has a relation to Table B.
Table B has a relation to Table A.

We load them at once into the system from another source.
To insert them correctly, we need to:

1. First, insert table A rows with an empty relationship column to object B
2. Insert the rows of the table B with the completed relationship column to the object A
3. Update the rows of table A again, but with a completed relationship column to object B (because only now records B have an Id and are in the system)

How is this situation called?

Edit:
This is not many to many relationship.
Row A points out to Row B, but it doesn't mean that Row B points out to Row A.
It is often business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think its called "bad design", it would be better to have a third table that links A and B

Comment: Not really since it's not many to many relationship. In business often we have relationships that points out to different business logic of a specific relationship.
I mean row A point out to point B but it doesn't mean that row B point out to row A.